# Rotate Around Point Towards Mouse

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

I'm thinking this should be a simple problem but I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this because there are so many things involved.

I am trying to rotate objects **defined by their center** around a **defined point** *besides the center* **to face the location of the mouse**

I have the defined point in the world space and the mouse's location in the world space as well as the center of each item.

*Please avoid giving answers on how to rotate towards mouse or how to rotate around a point individually - I'm trying to do both!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a fair interpretation of your question, rotating from "last frame" to "this frame",,
[image]

If you know the location of the point that you want the sprite to rotate about and you know the distance away from that point that you want the sprite to be, try this:

```
float radius = ?.?f; // distance from pivot point to sprite
Vector2 spritePivot = new Vector2(?, ?); //location of pivot point
Vector2 mouseToPoint = spritePivot - new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
mouseToPoint.Normalize();
float spriteAngle = MathHelper.Atan2(mouseToPoint.Y, mouseToPoint.X);
mouseToPoint *= radius;
Vector2 spriteLocation = spritePivot + mouseToPoint;
```

later, when drawing the sprite, use spriteAngle & spriteLocation as a params in the proper overload of SpriteBatch.Draw()

Dra

Comment: Does the formula change if the blue square is on the circle and closer to the blue mouse cursor? Also, does the formula change if the center of the blocks are on the circle?

Comment: Why do you use the .Normalize() method? Sorry for so many questions about you've been tremendously helpful with that diagram

Comment: ans1, no, as long as you adjust spritePivot & radius (distance from sprite to pivot) the rest of the algorithm will work.

Comment: ans2, Normalize() is used for 2 reasons. a.) the Atan2() requires a vector of length 1 to properly find the angle. b.) to convert 'mouseToPivot' to a magnitude of 1 so when multiplied by radius, it will be the correct length for adding. - Since both a & b need a vector of unit length (a magnitude of 1), it was handy to normalize the vector at that stage.

Comment: Atan2 is not in the MathHelper namespace, it's in the Math namespace... sry, should be: float spriteRotation = (float)Math.Atan2(...same...);

Comment: There is a bug with this solution. None of the items are being orbitted around the pivot point. Instead, their position (center) is being set to the position - pivotpoint and then they are being rotated around the center. Here is what I wrote...

Comment: float radius = Vector2.Distance(pp, pos
                            Vector2 spritePivot = new Vector2(pp.x, pp.y);
                            Vector2 mouseToPoint = spritePivot - new Vector2(MilitiaGame.Instance.curMousePos.X,
                                MilitiaGame.Instance.curMousePos.Y);
                            mouseToPoint.Normalize();
                            
                            item.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(mouseToPoint.Y, mouseToPoint.X);
                            item.Position = spritePivot + mouseToPoint;

Comment: Steve is there any way to reach you besides this incredibly restrictive comment section? I'd like to share with you pictures of my game to show you the problem but I don't want to release these on the public internet.